# Strlen in Malloc

Tags: c, pointers

Why does this return no warnings? What is supposed to be wrong with the code?

```
char *str = malloc(strlen("hello" + 1));
strcpy(str, "hello");
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is this an interview question?

Comment: it would be a very nice interview question for advanced C programmers @MrLister

Comment: @Gewure Yes. Also, I just noticed that none of the answers point out that adding 1 to "hello" subtracts 1 from the result (i.e. `strlen("hello" + 1)` returns one less that the length of "hello"), but you cannot write `strlen("hello" - 1)` to add 1, in order to get the right length. Oh well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This

```
char *str = malloc(strlen("hello" + 1));
strcpy(str, "hello");
```

is nearly equivalent to:

```
char *temp = "hello";
char *temp2 = temp + 1;

char *str = malloc(strlen(temp2));
strcpy(str, "hello");
```

so `temp + 1` is pointer math (it returns a pointer to `ello`, and `strcpy` doesn't check if enough memory is present at destination ("standard" memory corruption caused by faulty code in C)

The end result is that `strlen` returns 4, `strcpy` uses 6 bytes of memory and a random piece of heap is trashed.

Answer (score 9):

Why would you expect warnings?

The code is broken because you should be doing `strlen("hello") + 1`, not `strlen("hello" + 1)` (which is equivalent to `strlen("ello")`).

Comment: Right.. I guess my question then is why is `strlen("hello" + 1)` equivalent to `strlen("ello")`?

Comment: @quantum Because a string literal is an array of characters. If you had a named string `str` with the value "hello", `str+1` would also point to the second character in `str`, the `e`. So if you, for instance, print it, it would also print out "ello". Does that help?

Comment: A string literal is a pointer to the first character of that string (in a `char[]`). If you add 1 you move that pointer one array element further, i.e. cut off the first character of the string.

Answer (score 1):

The below statement is incorrect.

```
char *str = malloc(strlen("hello" + 1));
```

It should be

```
char *str = malloc(strlen("hello") + 1);
```

strlen in this case would probably return you a value of 4 instead of 5 and strcpy will lead to Out of Bounds write. Execute the program with a memory analyzer and it shall point out an error to you.